# How to open a multiple file spanned zip file using only windows standard tools?

Tags: windows-7, windows, zip

I have a large file that I want to send via email.  To get round size limits I can use 7-zip to create a multiple file zip archive and then send the files one per email.  Putting this back together with 7-zip is trivial.  Unfortunately the recipient has only standard Windows 7 tools available and is not permitted to install other software.  Any idea how they can reconstruct and unzip the file please?

Thanks,  Dave.

Comment: Okay I have an ugly answer using the cmd prompt, but the target users are *really* not that techie:   copy /b file.zip.001+file.zip.002 file.zip

Comment: Good, please enter the answer once the timeout for answering yourself expires. Probably you can make it better for non-"techies" by creating a `.bat` or `.cmd` script.